# 2 Column DIV/Table for Taxonomies - Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am using 10 custom taxonomies for woocommerce in wordpress and would like to display them in a 2 column div or table on the product page. Not every taxonomy is completed for every item, some may have all and some may only have 1.

At the moment I have created the first column (to show the taxonomy name) using

```
echo '<div class="tasting-notes">';
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'classifications' ) ) { echo '<li>Classification:</li>';}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'producers' ) ) { echo '<li>Producer:</li>';}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'milk_source' ) ) { echo '<li>Milk Type:</li>';}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'food_pairings' ) ) { echo '<li>Food Pairing:</li> ';}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'drink_pairings' ) ) { echo '<li>Drink Pairing:</li>';}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'distribution' ) ) { echo '<li>Distribution:</li> ';}
echo '</div>';
```

and the second column (to show taxonomy result(s) ) using

```
echo '<div class="tasting-notes">';
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'classifications' ) ) { echo '<li>' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'classifications', '',  ', ' );}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'producers' ) ) { echo '<li>' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'producers', '',  ', ' );}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'food_pairings' ) ) { echo '<li>' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'food_pairings', '',  ' | ' );}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'drink_pairings' ) ) { echo '<li>' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'drink_pairings', '',  ' | ' );}
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'distribution' ) ) { echo '<li>' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'distribution', '',  ' | ' );}
    
    echo '</div>';
```

This seems to work ok, except my problem is when one of the taxonomies wraps into a second line, it wraps column 2 but not column 1. So the taxonomy headers and results do not align.

I also tried to return both the taxonomy header and name in the one query using the following

```
   if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'producers' ) ) { echo 'ProducerS:' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'producers', '',  ', ' );}
```

That also works except when one of the results is empty and I can see the blank div. I tried with tables and ran into the same errors.

Please explain how to show 2 columns with Taxonomy and matching results that is also fluid and allows for empty taxonomies.

Example image with food pairing not wrapping correctly ↓

[image: example image with food pairing not wrapping correctly]

This made more sense in my head.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I am bringing them into elementor 2 column block that is added to each product.

Comment: from an HTML perspective, shouldn't that be a `<ul>` wrapping all the list tags instead of a `<div>`?

Comment: Yes I think you are right, sorry I originally had it as a table,